# Нужно создать HTML элемент(button) с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

Пробую этот код, но ничего не получается

```
let newDiv = document.createElement('div')
let tone = document.createElement('button');
tone.textContent = 'Темнее';
tone.setAttribute('type', 'button');
newDiv.append('tone');
document.write(tone);
```

Comment: зачем вы создаете `newDiv` если все равно не добавляете на страницу?

Comment: а по другому ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Потому что добавляем как
`document.body.appendChild(tone);`

`document.write()` работает, когда страница находится в процессе загрузки

Answer (score 0):

1. В `newDiv.append('tone');` `'tone'` -- просто слово, а не значение переменной `tone`.
2. У элемента есть `appendChild`.
3. `newDiv` так и не добавлен.
4. `document.write` работает со строкой, а не с элементом.

Читайте документацию по js и DOM. Пробуйте примеры еще проще.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос звучит таким образом: `Нужно создать HTML элемент(button) с помощью javascript`

Можно так, используя `createElement`

```js
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'Нажми';
button.classList.add('btn');
document.body.append(button);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Или так, используя `insertAdjacentHTML`

```js
const button = '<button class="btn">Нажми</button>'
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', button);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @YoungCoder если мой ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос, отметьте его галочкой(возле голосов находится)

Comment: черт, не могу найти

Comment: @YoungCoder там есть стрелочки вверх и вниз, а посередине 0(это голоса), ниже этого находится галочка серая, если вы на неё кликните, она станет зелёной этот будет означать, что этот ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос